# grep command that works on Ubuntu, but not on Fedora

Tags: grep, fedora

I clean hacked Wordpress installations for clients on a regular basis, and I have a set of scripts that I have written to help me track down where the sites are hacked. One code snippet that I use on a regular basis worked fine on Ubuntu, but since switching to Fedora on Friday has quite behaving as expected. The command is this:

```
grep -Iri --exclude "*.js" "eval\s*(" * | grep -rivf ~/safeevals.txt >../foundevals.txt;
```

What it is supposed to happen (and did happen when I was using Ubuntu): grep through all non-binary files, excluding Javascript includes, for all occurances of the eval() function, then perform a negative match on a line by line basis against all known occurances of the eval() function in a vanilla installation of Wordpress (the patterns of which are in ~/safeevals.txt).

What is actually happening: The first part is working fine, as I ran it separately and it did find all instances of eval() in the installation. However, instead of greping through those results, after the pipe is it re-grepping through all of the files, returning a negative match of ~/safeevals.txt (ie. pretty much every line of every file in the installation).

Any idea why the second grep isn't acting on the piped data, or what I need to do to fix it? Thanks.

-Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tested on my Debian box: apparently, `grep -r` likes to assume a default argument of `.`. I am really wondering if that behaviour is valid. Anyway, I guess dropping the `-r` option from the second `grep` command will fix it.

**Edit:** rgrep defaulting to $PWD seems to be a recent change in grep, see [this discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38793/where-does-grep-r-search-by-default) on unix.stackexchange and the link there to the commit in the upstream grep code repository.

Comment: Removing the -r flag did it, thanks! I have no idea why I had that in there in the first place but apparently in the old version of grep it did nothing.